# C++/CLI multiple errors

Tags: visual-c++

I am getting multiple, confusing errors when building this school assignment and am hoping for some direction on what might be the problem.  I wouldn't normally write it like this, but I put everything into one file as I try to debug this.  Using Visual Studios Express 2012.  I'm getting over 30 errors when I build, so I'm sure there is something fundamental that I am simply overlooking.  Just a suggestion please, not looking for anyone to do my homework.  Thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "MessageDisplayClass.h"
#include "LogMessageClass.h"
#include "TimerEventArgs.h"

using namespace System;

ref class CustomTimerClass
{

private:
static bool stopFlag = false;

// create instance of TimerEventArgs
TimerEventArgs^ timerEvent;

public:
CustomTimerClass(void)
{
}
delegate void CustomTimerClass::TimerAlarmHandler(/*Object^ sender, TimerEventArgs^ args*/);
event CustomTimerClass::TimerAlarmHandler^ OnTimerAlarm;

property bool StopFlag
{
    bool get(void)
    {
        return stopFlag;
    }

    void set(bool b)
    {
        stopFlag = b;
    }
}

void run()
{
    Sleep(1000);
    raiseTimerAlarm();
}

void OnStart()
{
    // create instances of DisplayMessageClass and LogMessageClass classes
    DisplayMessageClass^ messageDisplayer = gcnew DisplayMessageClass(this);
    LogMessageClass^ messageLogger = gcnew LogMessageClass(this);

    // display and log messages concerning this event
    messageDisplayer->displayMessage(this, timerEvent);
    messageLogger->logMessage(this, timerEvent);
}

void raiseTimerAlarm()
{
    // create instance of TimerEventArgs and get time of instance creation
    timerEvent = gcnew TimerEventArgs();
    String^ eventTime = timerEvent->EventTime;

    // tie this instance of CustomTimerClass to OnTimerAlarm event and start event
    this->OnTimerAlarm += gcnew TimerAlarmHandler(this, &CustomTimerClass::OnStart);
    OnTimerAlarm();
}
};

ref class MainProgram
{
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    CustomTimerClass^ timerClass = gcnew CustomTimerClass();
    DisplayMessageClass^ messageClass = gcnew DisplayMessageClass();
    LogMessageClass^ logerClass = gcnew LogMessageClass();
    timerClass->run();
    return 0;
}
};
```

Comment: This looks like managed C++ code (.NET) and you might be trying to compile it as normal C++ code. What's the first error message you get?

Comment: error C2065 'CustomTimerClass': undeclared identifier.  It's like none of my declarations are recognized.

Comment: At the point you're trying to use it, the compiler doesn't know about it yet. Move your `main()` function to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks, but no help.  Getting 19 errors (first is this:  error C2143:  syntax error:  missing ';' before '^' at 8th line in CustomTimerClass, where I declare TimerEventArgs^ timerEvent;).

Comment: Same problem as before. You're trying to use TimerEventArgs before the compiler knows about it. This is why you should split each class into its own header file. I'll update my answer below.

Comment: You're not missing a semicolon in one of the header files?

Comment: I don't see any missing semicolons.  I think it has something to do with my includes:  MessageDisplayClass and LogMessageClass both #include "CustomTimerClass.h", and CustomTimerClass.h #includes both of the other two classes.  I just don't think that's right, but can't figure out how to get around it.  Could this be causing my problem?  The TimerEventArgs class does not include the CutomTimerClass, and it's the only one that doesn't seem to have any errors popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone else (other newbies):  As it turns out, my suspicion that the problem lay in the fact that some of the classes were "#including" each other was the problem.  Using forward declarations, combined with having to create a separate class altogether to act as a variable storage handler was the solution to my problem.

Here are the two classes that were giving me the biggest problem, corrected to function correctly:

```
/*
CustomTimerClass.h
*/

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "LogMessageClass.h"
#include "MessageDisplayClass.h"
#include "TimerEventArgs.h"
#include "Variables.h"

//ref class MessageDisplayClass;
//ref class Variables;

using namespace System;

ref class CustomTimerClass
{

private:
static bool stopFlag = false;

// create instance of TimerEventArgs
TimerEventArgs^ timerEvent;

// create instance of MessageDisplayClass and LogMessageClass
MessageDisplayClass^ messageDisplayer;
LogMessageClass^ messageLogger;

Variables^ flagVariable;

public:
CustomTimerClass(void)
{
}

delegate void CustomTimerClass::TimerAlarmHandler();
event CustomTimerClass::TimerAlarmHandler^ OnTimerAlarm;

property bool StopFlag
{
    bool get(void)
    {
        return stopFlag;
    }

    void set(bool b)
    {
        stopFlag = flagVariable->Flag;
    }
}

void run()
{
    Sleep(1000);
    raiseTimerAlarm();
}

void OnStart()
{
    // create instances of DisplayMessageClass and LogMessageClass classes
    messageDisplayer = gcnew MessageDisplayClass(this, flagVariable);
    messageLogger = gcnew LogMessageClass(this);

    // display and log messages concerning this event
    messageDisplayer->displayMessage(this, timerEvent);
    messageLogger->logMessage(this, timerEvent);
}

void raiseTimerAlarm()
{
    // create instance of TimerEventArgs and get time of instance creation
    timerEvent = gcnew TimerEventArgs();
    String^ eventTime = timerEvent->EventTime;

    // tie this instance of CustomTimerClass to OnTimerAlarm event and start event
    this->OnTimerAlarm += gcnew TimerAlarmHandler(this, &CustomTimerClass::OnStart);
    OnTimerAlarm();
}
};

/*
MessageDisplayClass serves to display a message that 
represents the time at which the TimerEventArgs class is 
instantiated.  This time is returned through a function
of TimerEventArgs class.
*/

#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "TimerEventArgs.h"
#include "Variables.h"

using namespace System;

ref class CustomTimerClass; // FORWARD DECLARATION HERE  CAN
                        // ONLY BE USED FOR REFERENCE.  CANNOT
                        // BE USED WHEN METHODS OF THE     CLASS
                        // ARE CALLED

ref class MessageDisplayClass
{

private:
CustomTimerClass^ customTimerRef;

// Variables CLASS CREATED SOLELY TO ACT AS GO-BETWEEN BETWEEN
// MessageDisplayClass and CustomTimerClass
Variables^ variableRef;         

static int counter;
public:

// constructor
MessageDisplayClass(CustomTimerClass^ CustomTimerClassInput, Variables^ variableReference)
{
    customTimerRef = CustomTimerClassInput;
    variableRef = gcnew Variables (CustomTimerClassInput); 
}

void displayMessage(Object^ sender, TimerEventArgs^ timer)
{
    counter ++;
    if (counter > 0)
    {
        variableRef->Flag = true;
        Console::WriteLine("Message:  an event occured at time stamp: " + timer->EventTime);
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point you're trying to use the various classes, the compiler doesn't know about them yet. Move your `main()` function to the end of the file. Or better, split your class definitions in their own header files and then include them in your main source file.

There are other related problems too. For example, you're trying to use the `TimerEventArgs` class before the compiler knows about it. So you need to move the class definition up. This is why it's best to have each class in its own header file, and then include it where needed. Though it's not strictly unnecessary, if you declare/define everything in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks, but no help (I originally had them in separate header files but modified it to what you see above for simplicity sake in requesting help.  Moved main to end of file with no luck.

Comment: @deadEddie You also need to move the classes to a place before you first use them. For example in `CustomTimerClass` you're trying to use `TimerEventArgs`. But you didn't define that yet. So move the `TimerEventArgs` class definition *before* the `CustomTimerClass` one.

Comment: Thanks, but still have issues.  Have put TimerEventArgs, DisplayMessage, and LogMessage classes into their own .h files and the file I originaly posted now looks like I have edited it above.  Still not recognizing class references

Comment: How do I change how it's being compiled if that's the problem?

Comment: first error is: error C2065: 'DisplayMessageClass' : undeclared identifier at first line in OnStart method.  Second error is:  error C2065: 'messageDisplayer' : undeclared identifier on same line.

Comment: One of your #include's is MessageDisplayClass.h. Maybe the class is MessageDisplayClass and not DisplayMessageClass?

Comment: Thank you. That was sloppy, and I corrected it, but not the underlying problem (when I comment out that include, I get an intellisense error on the line where the class is instantiated, and the error goes away when I uncomment it.  That's what is weird to me:  I have no intellisense errors, but am getting all these compile errors.

Comment: Did you try what I said about compiling as C++/CLI?

Comment: Not sure how to change it.  Right now my Common Language Runtime Support is set to Common Language Runtime Support (/clr).

Comment: Yes, that's the right setting. So what other error are you getting?

Comment: First 7 errors are:Error 1 error C2065: 'DisplayMessageClass' : undeclared identifier
Error 2 error C2065: 'messageDisplayer' : undeclared identifier 
Error 3 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DisplayMessageClass'
Error 4 error C2065: 'LogMessageClass' : undeclared identifier 
Error 5 error C2065: 'messageLogger' : undeclared identifier 
Error 6 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LogMessageClass' 
Error 7 error C2065: 'messageDisplayer' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Error 8 error C2227: left of '->displayMessage' must point to class/struct/union/generic type 
Error 9 error C2065: 'messageLogger' : undeclared identifier 
Error 10 error C2227: left of '->logMessage' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
Error 11 error C2065: 'DisplayMessageClass' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Whenever you get an "undeclared identifier" error, that always means that the compiler doesn't know yet about that specific class. You probably defined that class too late or, if its in a header file, forgot to include it.

Comment: OK, we already established that the class name is MessageDisplayClass and not DisplayMessageClass. Didn't you fix it? And I don't know what's the problem with LogMessageClass, but it could be something similar.

Comment: Well, I did correct that, but the MessageDisplayClass is still not being recognized so all the same errors still apply. I don't see any problems with the LogMessageClass syntax.

Comment: It could also be a problem with the precompiled header. Disable precompiled headers by going to **Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers -> Precompiled Header** and set it to **Not Using Precompiled Headers**. Then try compiling. Also, Windows.h should be included in the precompiled header (StdAfx.h), not in any other file.

Comment: moved windows.h (didn't know that - thanks) and adjusted my Precompiled Headers setting as recommended.  No help.

Comment: Oops, I forgot you also need to right-click stdafx.cpp (not stdafx.h) and do the same to disable precompiled headers.

Comment: All my added classes are just header files (no .cpp file for constuctor).  That wouldn't be a problem, would it?

Comment: Anyway, if you got the order of declarations right, are compiling as C++/CLI, have no typos in the class names, and have no problems with the precompiled header, I have no idea what might be the issue, sorry :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18386/discussion-between-deadeddie-and-user1610015)

Answer (score 0):

Other than wrong order of declarations, it looks like the problem is that the compiler doesn't recognize the ^ bit, which suggests you're not compiling as C++/CLI. Righ-click the project in **Solution Explorer** and go to **Configuration Properties -> General**, and make sure that **Common Language Runtime Support** is set to **Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I checked it and it was set as you recommend.